# XCOM 2 - customize soldiers from living quarters?

Tags: xcom-2

Are you able to customize soldiers/scientists/engineers from the living quarter screen?

It seems that only way how to customize soldiers are from the pre-mission screen but there is no way how to customize scientists/engineers?

Edited: It seems that it's possible to customize soldiers from Armory screen where is also located `View solders` menu item.  But the same doesn't work for scientists/engineers from `Research` or `Engineering` screen.

Comment: "customize soldiers are from before-missing screen" - I suppose it's nice you get advanced notice that they will be going AWOL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.  The only thing you can do in the Living Quarters screen is to view what soldiers you have, the scientists you have, and the engineers you have.

The only way to customize your soldiers is, like you said, either from the Armory or in the mission deploy screen.  You can't customize engineers and scientists.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize scientists and engineers BEFORE you start a game. But not after. In the character pool mode you can create people and mark them as VIP only.

When the game imports VIPs from this list, they will be named and customized as you created them.